# No Packets Received - Hyper-V Guest (Server 2008R2)

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I have just installed a new Hyper-V host machine running Server 2008 R2. Created the first VM (also Server 2008 R2 SP1) and all is working apart from a bizare problem with network packets.

Host machine has two Intel Nic's one is dedicated to Hyper-V and is setup as an "External" network in Virtual Network Manager. It's also removed from the management OS, so dedicated just to Hyper-V. (We have two other Hyper-V hosts with the exact config).

The guest machine was installed and connected to this virtual network, but the guest OS can not receive network packets, it only sends. I configured a manual static IP but still nothing.

It has however managed to pick up an IPv6 address from one of our routers that hands them out, pinging the address does not work and I am unable to ping IPv6 addresses from the guest machine.

Suggestions? I have double checked as many settings as I can think of compared to our other hosts, but this is just weird!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the Hyper-V role and adding it again resolved this problem. I also reinstalled the guest O/S.

I would have liked to figure out what was actually broken!